# vuex unknown action type: addToCart

Tags: vue.js, vuex

hello everyone im trying to add product into cart array so i can render it after , i used vuex but i got this error : Console was cleared
[vuex] unknown action type: addToCart
hopefully u can give me some hint so i can fix this issue
thank you so much !!

here is the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-minsky-9cig7?file=/src/components/Products.vue

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="shopTitle">
      <h1>Shop</h1>
    </div>
    <section class="categoriesSection">
      <ul class="categories">
        <li>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectedCategory ='All'">See All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectedCategory ='Shoes'">Shoes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectedCategory ='Suits'">Suits</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="products">
        <div class="product" v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.productId">
          <div class="imgproduct"></div>

          <div class="productDetails">
            <div>
              <h1>{{product.productTitle}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <i onClickButton class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{{product.productPrice}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <i onClickButton @click="addToCart(product)" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    selectedCategory: {
      // getter
      get: function() {
        return this.$store.getters.selectedCategory;
      },
      // setter
      set: function(newValue) {
        return this.$store.commit("updateCategory", newValue);
      }
    },

    filteredProducts() {
      return this.$store.getters.filteredProducts;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart: function(product) {
      this.$store.dispatch("addToCart", product);

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `mutation` called `addToCart` but no `action` either create an `action` called `addToCart` or just call the mutation directly :

```
this.$store.commit("addToCart", product);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you show me where i can call the mutation

Comment: Products.vue line 151

Comment: In your `store.js` add a sub object called `actions`, just like you did with `mutations`. You're calling an action with `store.dispatch`. Call a `mutation` instead with `store.commit` like you did in other parts of your code. Google vuex docs for more info, there are slight differences between actions and mutations, mostly in how you get reference to commit (via first paramater being an object containing what you need). Cheers

Comment: thank you , it worked but i got another error i can add just one product to the cart array after trying to add the second product it gives me this error [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: itemToAdd is not defined